# Change elements to iterate over while iterating over list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

This may not be a Python specific question, but here it goes:

I am trying to solve a numerical problem of the type in which I have to show which elements in a list a = [a_1,a_2,a_3,...] have some property X. However, when I prove it for some a_n, I will sometimes also prove it for other element(s) a_m in the list. So, to speed up the algorithm, I don't want to do the test those elements again.

Now, I can create a list has_property_X and, while iterating over a, test if each element is in the list (and populating that list after testing each element). However, I still have to go through each element in doing this.

Is there a smarter approach?

Comment: Is *m* guaranteed to be less than *n*?  (or is *m* guaranteed to be greater than *n*?)

Comment: @zachdj if m is ever less than n, then the "bonus proof" is superfluous, because `a_m` was already proved before you reach `a_n`. So the efficiency gain is only in the case where m > n. There might, however, be some benefit of sorting the list somehow so that elements likely to produce many "bonus proofs" appear at the start of the list.

Comment: @kaya3 the sorting trick is what I had in mind.  If *m* is less than *n*, then OP can improve efficiency by iterating over the list in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is replace your list `has_property_X` with a lookup table (dictionary).  The lookup table will keep track of each `a_i`.  The key will be `a_i` and the value will be one of

- `None`, if the element has not yet been processed
- `True`, if the element has the property
- `False`, if the element does not have the property.

This gives you complexity O(1) for checking if an element has already been processed.  It would look something like this:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # your list `a`
lookup_table = {a_i: None for a_i in a}

for element in a:
    if lookup_table[element] is None:
        # determine if element has the property
        element_has_property = False

        # if, in the process, you determine that another element `a_m` also has the property,
        # then set lookup_table[a_m] = True
        lookup_table[element] = element_has_property

# assemble list of elements which have the target property
has_property_x = [a_i for a_i in lookup_table if lookup_table[a_i] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct, in the sense that the cost of time occurs in compute each `a_i`, and not in the lists loop . If you loop over the list `a` with a stop list `has_x_property` (or maybe a set if the repeated values don't matter)

```
for elem in a:
    if elem not in has_property_x:
        algoritm(elem)
        update(has_property_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

While thinking a bit longer about it, I thought of the following approach:

```
a = [a_1,a_2,a_3...] #the list
has_property_X = []

while a!=[]:
    #algorithm that tests and removes a[0] and appends to has_property_X the elements that 
    #do and removes them from a as well
```

I don't know how good of an approach this is (lets say, compared to zachdj's). However, it does answer the question, and I don't see why it will do any worse...